# How start a script on startup automatically on PXE booting linux

Tags: process, virtual-machine, services, background-process, pxe

I have a virtual machine that is PXE booted. How can I start a script to run as a background on startup without having to manually start it?

I have tried the following things, and they do not work.

1. Modifying the `/etc/rc.local`
2. Adding it to the `/etc/init.d` and updating the `update-rc.d`
3. I cannot install any packages, so `upstart` won't be an option.

When I modify the `rc.local`, the virtual machine crashes. Also `update-rc.d` is not available.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why you cannot install any of packages? Which form of your system image? Is it unpacked on NFS server or in image file?

Comment: Well I am a newbie so I don't really know. But I guess it's sort of a minimalistic `VMkernel`. It doesn't even recognize `sudo` or `apt-get` for any reason.

Comment: Your VM machine is booting. Loader (I assume that this is pxelinux) loads kernel and initrd from TFTP servers. So Where remain system (root folder with /bin /etc ...) is located and what form of it (directory, iso image, archive)?

Comment: The root folder is present locally inside the VM only. It is a directory.

Comment: You can `chroot` to this directory from working system and install all needed packages. Is it appropriate solution for you?

Comment: `chroot` is not found! :(

Comment: Boot your VM with any Live CD, mount your local VM directory and chroot to it. Install what you need and all should works.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use `crontab`, you can add :

```
@reboot your_script.sh
```

Comment: I can't use that as well :/